# Is it possible to find html attributes with specific start? (not specific value)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, razor

Imagine that you have the following button:

```
<button id="id" data-trigger-function = "true", data-value-1="12345", data-value-guid="534-534-657647365-gd">Click Me for Function</button>
```

Is it possible, to get something like the following in the called function:

```
$(this).attr('data-value-'+  * ).each(...);
```

The objective would be to use a universal selector in the attribute name, and not in the attribute value (not something like this: [name^='something']). The objective is to get the values of data-value-1 and data-value-guid because they both have the same start.., this means that data-value could be, data-value-qwerty, data-value-xpto, without having to know the *.

I've searched this, but couldn't find anything like this, or any mentions to something like this. Is it possible?

Thank you! (sorry for the bad english)

Comment: seems like this impossible and better and simples use class instead

Comment: @Grundy it is not at all impossible.

Comment: @Pointy i mean this impossibly with one simple selector like `[name="..."]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could get all attributes and loop through them:

```
$.each(this.attributes, function(index, attr){
    var name = attr.name;

    if(name.startsWith('data-value') {
        var value = attr.value;

        //You code goes here
    }
});
```

Comment: what `this` in this context?

Comment: `this`in Javascript always means the function which called the actual one

Comment: @Grundy it would be a reference to a DOM node, like you'd have inside a jQuery event handler for example.

Comment: @messerbill no, that's not what `this` means.

Comment: @Pointym now it seems like a some global. DavidG can you provide how call this?

Comment: @Grundy Well in the OPs original code you can see he already has a `this` reference which is likely referring to a DOM element.

Comment: damn, missed this :-D

Comment: This made it to me... it's a nice hack :) thank you @DavidG

Answer (score 1):

Another option:

You may also choose to iterate thru the `data-*` only and filter our the ones that start with `value` like below:

```
$.each($("button").data(), function(key, val) {
    if (key.match(/^value/i)) {
        alert (key + ": " + val);
    }
})
```

Note: the above requires you to change `data-value-1="12345"` to something like `data-value-one="12345"`

[**A Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/d2eb8z3p/)